# x86 assembly: How can i rewrite an interrupt?

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt, x86-16, emu8086

I'm trying to rewrite the 0h interrupt (Divide by zero) to a custom label I've made, which is supposed to print a custom message I've made instead of the normal exception which the emulator throws.

I haven't managed to find a good source which explains all this stuff in a good and understandable way, so my code obviously didn't work when I first made it. I've found this post: [Is it possible to make a custom Interrupt in Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464329/is-it-possible-to-make-a-custom-interrupt-in-assembly) But I'm still confused.

```
org 100h


jmp main


main:
    xor ax, ax
    mov es, ax    
    CLI
    mov bx, offset divideByZero
    mov es:[0h], bx 
    add bx, 2
    mov ax, cx
    mov es:[bx], ax 
    STI


    mov ax, 10
    mov bx, 0
    div bx

    mov ah, 0
    int 16h
    ret

divideByZero:
    push bp 
    mov bp, sp 

    PRINTN "Error: Divide By Zero Can Break The Universe" 

    pop bp
    iret
```

Can somebody explain to me how can I make my own interrupt like I tried to do, and how does it work?

Comment: `offset divideByZero` isn't the full linear address of your function.  You need to store `cs` to linear address `2` (i.e. `es:[2]`), not to `divideByZero+2`

Comment: I afraid that I didn't understand you. What do I need to do? and why?

Comment: @PeterCordes forgot to mention, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code where you set the interrupt vector.  `add bx,2` is completely unnecessary, `mov ax,cx` should be `mov ax,cs`, and `mov es:[bx],ax` should be `mov es:[2],ax`.

I'll also mention that while the original 8086 (and EMU8086) pushes the address of the instruction after the divide when a divide-by-zero (or overflow) occurs, on later chips the return address will be the same `div` instruction that just faulted.  So on these later chips when you execute the `iret` you will go back to the `div bx` and trigger another division by zero.  Then the handler will either need to abort the process (easy) or make appropriate changes to the saved registers and/or return address before executing the `iret` (difficult).

Comment: [`mov r/m16, Sreg` is a valid encoding](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov); there's no need for AX here.  Just `mov es:[2], cs`.  But well spotted that CX was a typo for CS; I assumed it was just some nonsense related to their confusion with storing *to* the function address in BX.  (There's also no need for `bx`; `mov r/m16, imm16` is also a valid encoding.  It does take 2 instructions to zero a segment register, though.)

Comment: Are you sure emu8086 doesn't emulate a real 8086 and take `#DE` exceptions with the address of the instruction *after* `div`?  Only later x86 changed that.  [Why do call and jump instruction use a displacement relative to the next instruction, not current?](//stackoverflow.com/q/58720936) points out that original 8086 probably doesn't even keep track of the real instruction start address (even if you exclude multiple prefixes, which it unfortunately does for resuming from `rep movs`)

Comment: @PeterCordes : EMU8086 does in fact emulate the behaviour of an 8086 in this regard. EMU8086 will return to the next instruction after the DIV

Comment: @PeterCordes I've rephrased things to account for the different 8086 behavior with exceptions, but have left the explanation of the behavior for later chips.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks for that confirmation.  I haven't had much time available to look into details like that.