# Which system call is called for strcpy or strcat C++ functions?

Tags: linux, system-calls

I was wondering if strcpy or strcat like functions causes any system call or they are handled internally by the OS?

Comment: When in doubt, you can run your binary through `strace` which will show you system calls that the binary performs.

Comment: yes. i did that. and strace doesn't show any system call for those functions. that made me ask you guys... how this kind of operation is handled? is there any way to catch those events?

Comment: You can try the [ltrace](http://ltrace.alioth.debian.org/) for library traces. The str functions don't make system calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux, those calls are implemented by the standard library (and those are part of the standard C library). See also [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). System calls are invocations from user code to kernel code for hardware access (e.g. memory allocation); they are accomplished with an [interrupt 0x80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817577/what-does-int-0x80-mean-in-assembly-code).

Comment: Yes, but this fact gives no information pertaining systems calls.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Added some general information pertaining to system calls.

Comment: Yes it does: these functions are implemented in the C runtime library which is regular unprivileged code, NOT a system call which is a call to privileged OS functions in the kernel.

Answer (score 6):

No system call is involved. In fact, the source code of most if not all implementations would look like [this](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262/ppc/gen/strcpy.c):

```
char * 
strcpy(char *s1, const char *s2) { 
    char *s = s1; 
    while ((*s++ = *s2++) != 0) ;
    return (s1);
}
```

`strcat` [is similar](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262/ppc/gen/strcat.c):

```
char *
strcat(char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    strcpy(&s1[strlen(s1)], s2);
    return s1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No OS calls are REQUIRED for such simple operations - they can be performed easily in the libraries.

Note that the OS may be entered during such calls, eg. because they generate a page-fault or some other hardware interrupt occurs.